# Infinite Continued Fraction Notation

Tags: notation, continued-fractions

I can't find anywhere via googling; is there some sort of $\sum$ like notation for infinite continued fractions? In other words, for a sum we do this:

$$
1+x+x^2+x^3+... = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n
$$

Easy, this notation is well known. Now, for a continued fraction:

$$
\pi= 3 + \dfrac{1}{6+\dfrac{9}{6+\dfrac{25}{6+\dfrac{49}{6+...}}}}
$$

This could be defined recursively, i.e. $\pi = F_0$ where:

$$
F_n=
\begin{cases}
3 + \dfrac{(2n+1)^n}{F_{n+1}} & n = 0\\
6 + \dfrac{(2n+1)^2}{F_{n+1}} & n \geq 1 \\
\end{cases}
$$

But this notation lacks the elegance of the $\sum$ example above. Even the notation for simple continued fractions isn't all that much of an improvement, i.e.

$$
\sqrt{2} = 1 + \dfrac{1}{2+\dfrac{1}{2+\dfrac{1}{2+...}}} = [1; 2, 2, 2, 2, ...]
$$

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) cites a notation by Gauss:
$$
x = a_0 + \dfrac{1}{a_1 + \dfrac{1}{a_2 + \dfrac{1}{a_3}}}
$$
would be written:
$$
x = a_0 + \mathop{\mathrm{K}}_{k = 1}^3 \frac{1}{a_k}
$$

Comment: So then $\pi = 3 + \mathop{\mathrm{K}}_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{(2k+1)^2}{6}$?

Comment: @durron597, that seems the logical extension of the notation.

Comment: However, it is pretty confusing since $\frac{(2k+1)^2}{6}\neq\frac{(4k+2)^2}{24}$.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the notation in
[Hatcher Topology of Numbers](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/TN/TNpage.html)
is the best notation. No sooner had I seen it than I got love with the notation. The notation is 
$$\pi=3
+{}^{1}\mkern-10mu\nearrow\mkern-8mu{}_{\normalsize 7}
+{}^{1}\mkern-10mu\nearrow\mkern-8mu{}_{\normalsize 15}
+{}^{1}\mkern-10mu\nearrow\mkern-8mu{}_{\normalsize 1}
+{}^{1}\mkern-10mu\nearrow\mkern-8mu{}_{\normalsize 292}
+{}^{1}\mkern-10mu\nearrow\mkern-8mu{}_{\normalsize 1}
+{}^{1}\mkern-10mu\nearrow\mkern-8mu{}_{\normalsize 1}
+\ldots$$